# Excel formula help sumif closed workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Thank you all for your help in solving the indirect issue, i have now realised that this formula doenst work with a closed workbook is there anyway around this so the formula will work when only the master file is open?

=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'[EURO.XLS]"&L1&" 2018'!$H$13:$H$75"),INDIRECT("'[EURO.XLS]"&L1&" 2018'!$A$13:$A$75"),">="&$B$15,INDIRECT("'[EURO.XLS]"&L1&" 2018'!$A$13:$A$75"),"<="&$B$90,INDIRECT("'[EURO.XLS]"&L1&" 2018'!$B$13:$B$75"),"*INT*")

Comment: Have a look on [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function.

Comment: Thought it might be indirect but cant seem to get it to work with an external workbook link

Comment: Please post the exact formula you've tried, and also the error message. Please don't answer in comment,  but update your question.

Comment: I got this simplified version to work: `=SUM(INDIRECT("'[EURO.xlsx]" & H3 & " 2018'!A1:A10"))`.  H3 contains JAN.  I got errors initially. The single quotes are important as is the space before 2018. Try a test using just one of your range references and build up from there.

Comment: It Should be like,  =SUM(INDIRECT( "[" & Test4B.xls & "]" &A6& 2018 & "!D1:D10")). And is working I've TESTED.

Comment: My suggestion is if "2018" has not any specific role then JAN2018 should be written in A6 and then the Formula should,, =SUM(INDIRECT(A6 &"!D1:D10")).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDIRECT` like below:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'[EURO.XLS]"&A1&" 2018'!$H$13:$H$75"),INDIRECT("'[EURO.XLS]"&A1&" 2018'!$A$13:$A$75"),"<="&$A$3&"-5",INDIRECT("'[EURO.XLS]"&A1&" 2018'!$B$13:$B$7"),"*Int*")
```

To break it down below is the sum range from your original formula.

```
INDIRECT(" '[EURO.XLS]" & A1 & " 2018'!$H$13:$H$75" )
```

Jan is now replaced by whatever is in `A1`, sort of like a string concatenation.

Comment: thank you all this solved the indirect issues, now looking for help on fixing the closed workbook issue